# Nested Avro Schema not parsing in schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, cloudera, hdp

Trying to Produce kafka messages with the below Avro schema. The Avro schema is not getting parsed properly in Schema registry but its parsing properly in the Online Avro schema validator.

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "test.sample",
  "name": "sample",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "source",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "null"
    },
    {
      "name": "data",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "data",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "request",
            "type": {
              "name": "request",
              "type": "record",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "name": "name",
                  "type": "string",
                  "default": "null"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "response",
            "type": {
              "name": "response",
              "type": "record",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "name": "dob",
                  "type": "int",
                  "default": "null"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The error which I get from Schema registry is : reader type: STRING not compatible with writer type: RECORD.

Could Someone help to understand what is wrong here.

Schema Registry 0.5.4 (Hortonworks 3.1.0.0) version.

Comment: Give the fields default values and try again. There's probably a conflict between your schema and schemas in the registry.

Comment: The schema registry schema is not a finished product, it works pretty good but there are a lot of issues/bugs.   I was able to copy your schema above and +Add it to a schema in Schema Registry.   Update your post with more information about how/what/when/where/why you were able to get the error. Also what versions...

Comment: @LuckyGuess I tried with default as null and still same issues.

Comment: @steven-dfheinz I am using HDP schema registry(post updated) to consume kafka Avro messages. The Avro messages in having nested Record type which i am trying to register the nested record schema and getting that error.

Comment: I figured thats what it was but you had confluent-schema-registry in the tags so I wasn't sure.   I literally copy pasted your json above into my schema registry and it worked fine.  I am on Schema Registry 0.7.0 and HDF-3.4.1.1     You know what this means:  0.5.4 won't allow that structure...      Can you upgrade?

Comment: @steven-dfheinz Thanks a lot. I hope next upgrade would be to CDP. Do you see any other way to handle this situation ?

Comment: Yes,  with ambari you can install w/e versions you want,  they just don't really tell you that...